# Change divs by clicking on one button

Tags: jquery

I am making a point and click game. In this game there will be some conversation between characters. I would like a jQuery function where clicking on the Next button will show the right conversation slide.
Clicking the researcher in game will trigger the first slide - researcherWords1.

Order:

1. researcherWords1
2. noniWords1
3. researcherWords2
4. noniWords2
5. researcherWords3
6. noniWords3
7. researcherWords4

HTML:

```
<div class="conversationWrapper">
    <div id="researcherConvo">Next</div>

    <!-- CONVERSATION WITH THE RESEARCHER -->
    <div class="researcherSays">
        <div class="researcherImage"></div>
        <div class="researcherWords1 researcher"></div>
        <div class="researcherWords2 researcher"></div>
        <div class="researcherWords3 researcher"></div>
        <div class="researcherWords4 researcher"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- NONIS REPLIES TO THE RESEARCHER -->
    <div class="noniSays">
        <div class="noniImage"></div>
        <div class="noniWords1"></div>
        <div class="noniWords2"></div>
        <div class="noniWords3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* CONVERSATION BOXES */
.conversationWrapper{
    position:fixed;
    width:1024px;
    height:768px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:none; /* Ta bort vid doling */
}
#researcherConvo{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:purple;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    margin:auto;
}
.researcherSays, .noniSays{
    position:absolute;
    height:150px;
    width:600px;
}
.researcherSays{
    top:50px;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.noniSays{
    bottom:50px;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.researcherImage, .noniImage{
    background-color:#fff;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
}
.researcherWords1, .researcherWords2, .researcherWords3, .researcherWords4, 
.noniWords1, .noniWords2, .noniWords3{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#aaa;
    width:450px;
    height:150px;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: I see a jQuery tag, but no jQuery code in your question. What jQuery have you tried?

Comment: I started something like this: $('#researcherConvo').click(function(){
  $('.researcher:first').effect('drop', {
   direction: 'down'
  });
 });
But couldn't go any further since I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach could look something like this:

```
var index = -1;
var divs = ['researcherWords1', 'noniWords1', 'researcherWords2',
    'noniWords2', 'researcherWords3', 'noniWords3', 'researcherWords4']
$('#researcherConvo').click(function() {
  index++;
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    $('div.'+divs[i]).hide();
  }
  $('div.'+divs[index]).show();
});
```

So just hiding all divs except the "current" one, which is determined by increasing the `index` to your array of `div`s.

(I'm assuming your CSS takes care of *where* to display what I'm assuming will be something like speechbubbles; this code just shows/hides the `div`s one at a time.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the trick! Is there a simple way now to add the effect down on these as well?

Comment: Glad it helped. By "add the effect down", do you mean the [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) effect? The [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) effect also has several options you might want to check out. Or are you talking about jqueryUI's [drop effect](https://api.jqueryui.com/drop-effect/)?

Comment: The `show()` could be replaced with something like: `show('slide', {direction: 'down'})` if that's what you want.

Comment: I tried that but then both researcherWords1 and noniWords1 disappear. The effect('drop', direction: 'down');. Sorry for not being clear enough!

Comment: Yep... have a look at the API documentation I linked to in my first comment. If you're still having trouble, try putting together a jsfiddle, and maybe ask a new question. Sorry, didn't initially see your comment on your question, and wasn't aware that a transition effect was part of your question.

Comment: That sure did it! Thank you for educating answers! I should learn how to read the API documentation, but I usually end up understanding nothing. :D

Comment: Hah, my pleasure. :-)